# How to extend section width: 100% using css

Tags: html, css, width

I have a section inside `width: 1180px;` i want to extend this green color div I want to make width: 100% I have tried using `vw` but not getting but some extra space is coming. can anyone suggest me? Is there any other way to do using CSS.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner {
  width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin-left: calc(-100vw/2 + 100%/2);
  margin-right: calc(-100vw/2 + 100%/2);
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why can't you just move it below the box if you want it to be wider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use negative margin - the only problem with this approach is that if the page gets a vertical scroll, this will add a horizontal scroll as 100vw doesn't take into account the 20px caused by the vertical scroll:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner {
  width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1180px) {
  .box2 {
    margin: 0 calc(((100vw - 1180px) / 2) * -1);
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I say in my comments, it would be better to just move the green div outside your wrapper

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the margin using media query. Initially you have a negative margin but after 1180px it will be a positive one creating the unwanted space. You also don't need to set `width` using `vw` unit. Keeping the default width is enough:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner {
  width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin-left: calc(-100vw/2 + 100%/2);
  margin-right: calc(-100vw/2 + 100%/2);
}
@media all and (max-width:1180px) {
  .box2 { 
    margin:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner {
  width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner {
  width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```