# Left align div to centered container

Tags: css

I have a container centered with a max width as follow:

```css
#container {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: 900px;
}
```

Now I want to create a new div just below the contained one, but I want this new div to align to the left and expand beyond the right side of the container. Something like that:

```
            ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                #container
            |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||     #div 2
```

The difficulty is that `#container` margins are `auto`, so how can I force `#div` to follow `#container` left margin as the browser resizes?!

**NOTE:** I am looking for a pure CSS solution WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT

**EDIT:** It was not clear in my explanation but, my goal was to make the `#div` ADJACENT to the `#container`. Like this:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="div"></div>
```

I ended up refactoring my html to use @bananabran solution with `absolute` positioning which simply uses parent-child structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53278683/8620333

Comment: My suggestion is to do CSS Flex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox . Check it out ...with that you don't have to do any more margin just do `display: flex;` and then you can align container `center` and div 2 to `flex-end`

Comment: Your question is not all that clear

Comment: Maybe you can put !important to the styles of second div container

Comment: You could use table for centering and second row with colspan=2.

Comment: @Riskbreaker False information, won't / can't work.

Comment: @Riskbreaker I'm just saying it can't be done with flexbox...

Comment: @VXp okok I get you...Ill defer to Paulie_D answer just because css grid is another option and its wrap in a parent just like flex would had too also

Comment: @Riskbreaker Yea but flex wouldn't give you the desired results, meanwhile grid is the simplest, elegant and modern solution.

Comment: @VXp agree on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to *force* the div to follow its container's left margin. Divs naturally start at the top-left of their container (unless otherwise specified or affected by). You also do not need to use Grid or FlexBox. CSS3, and even CSS2 can do this natively.

See working CodePen example: https://codepen.io/bananabrann/pen/QWWdXQZ

Assuming you have no other code affecting your code...

```html
<div id="container" />
  <div id="my-div" />
```

```
#container {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}
#my-div {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bananabrann, I had to refactor my code a bit because both div were adjacent, and not parent-child style... but your solution is cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 400px) 1fr;
  /* 400px for demo purposes */
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
  background: pink;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.wide-r {
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">Container
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, similique, maxime aspernatur dolorum quod recusandae possimus fuga blanditiis laudantium delectus quis magni. Veniam, consequuntur dolores facilis cupiditate fugiat ullam aspernatur!
      Corporis excepturi quos esse voluptatem voluptatibus corrupti ea, tempora culpa magni, hic aspernatur pariatur molestias itaque doloremque assumenda ad fugiat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wide-r">Wide Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D I am sure this is a good solution, however I am not quite comfortable with css-grid and bananabrann's solution is simpler to integrate with my code right now. Thanks again :)